# A Vandermonde-type system

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, polynomials, finite-fields

> For a prime $p$ and $a_1,\dotsc,a_n\in\mathbb F_p^\times$, consider the system of equations
>     $$ \begin{cases}
>    \begin{align}
>        a_1 + \dotsb + a_n &= 0 \\
>        a_1x_1 + \dotsb + a_nx_n &= 0 \\
>          \qquad &\ \vdots \\
>        a_1x_1^K + \dotsb + a_nx_n^K &= 0
>      \end{align} \end{cases}
>   $$
>   How large can $K$ be given that this system has a solution in the variables $x_1,\dotsc,x_n\in\mathbb F_p^\times$?

By the Chevalley–Warning theorem, if $n>K(K+1)/2$, then there are solutions with at least some of the variables distinct from $0$. Is it true, say, that if $K>C\sqrt n$ with a suitable absolute constant $C$, then the system does not have non-zero solutions? (For my purposes, it would be fine to know that there are no non-zero solutions with at least $2n/3$ among $x_1,\dotsc,x_n$ pairwise distinct.)

An essentially equivalent restatement of the problem is as follows:

> What is the smallest possible number of non-zero coefficients of a polynomial $P\in\mathbb F_p[x]$ of degree $\deg P\le p-1$ given that $P$ has a root of multiplicity $K$ at $x=1$?

There are many *similar* results and problems around (the Tarry-Escott problem, Linnik lemma, Vinogradov system, Borwein-Erdelyi-Kos results for polynomials over the integers, etc), and I suspect that the problem stated above has also been studied. Any references will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $P(x)$ is divisible by $(x-1)^K$ and $\deg P<p$, then $P$ has at least $K+1$ non-zero coefficients. Proof: divide $P$ by maximal possible power of $x$, take the derivative and use induction in $K$. Or what I get wrong?

Comment: This is perfectly correct and is attained on the polynomial $(x-1)^K$. I thought at some point of this polynomial, but somehow convinced myself that, translated back to the original system, it yields a solution with the $x_i$ equal to each other - which was totally wrong, as I now see. I will post a follow-up which is a closer approximation to the real problem that i need.